# Bash script to pack roughly 1GB of files into a tar archive

Tags: python, tar

I've got several folders with several thousand files, each folder roughly 3 - 10GB in size.
Now, I'd like to tar those files inside the folders and each tar file should be roughly 1GB in size.
Aftwards, I'd like to use Python to work on those tar files.

```
#!/bin/bash

dirlist=$(find $1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
stored_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date="-1 day")
#stored_date='2019-10-23'

for dir in $dirlist
do
(
    cd $dir
    tar_file=${PWD##*/}  
    tar_file="${tar_file}_${stored_date}.tar"

    echo "${tar_file}"

    tar -c $stored_date*.html --tape-length=1000M  -f ${tar_file}  --remove-files
)
done
```

It is working nicely to create the 1GB chunks - but with the ´--tape-length´ option, Python is running into all sorts of issues with

> tarfile.ReadError: unexpected end of data

(plus: I'd like to work with Python as well on the files with are split over the edge of a tar archive)

Is there a Linux solution to this?
I found star as opposed to tar but haven't tried it yet - I'd prefer to stay with the standard tar if possible.

Comment: `tar`on Linux is the non-standard `gtar` that is not recommended as it causes all kinds of compatibility issues unless you use `gtar` to unpack as well. In noticeable cases, `gtar` is even unable to unpack own archives. `star `is closer to the standard than `gtar`...

Comment: @schily: Please cite some sources for your claims about `gtar`. My cursory internet search doesn't show any, and the default version of `tar` packaged by the likes of debian is `gtar` (debian is currently at v1.30), not `star`. Maybe your memory is some snapshot of an ancient version or weird corner-case?

Comment: `gtar` has many of those corner cases that are never fixed even though they have been reported more than 20 years ago. If you live in a nutshell with only `gtar`available, is it obvious that you do not see most of the problems. Given that `gtar` needs at least 22 years to fix reported bugs, **ancient** is more or less the same as **recent**.

Comment: @schily - Does that mean you have no sources to cite, and no explanation why debian continues to package `gtar`? Does debian even package `star` as an alternative? What debian package should I use instead of their `tar`?

Comment: Debian is not an OSS friendly distro and do not expect Debian to change their tar implementation as they have a vendor lock in to `gtar`, caused by the quirks from the strange `gtar` option names that are in conflict with other tars and the non-standard archives from gtar. User friendly distros include a recent `star` package. So if you do not like to compile things yourself, do not use Debian. BTW: there are of course plenty of sources for the problems caused by the non-compliant gtar archives, but you need to search for them and I do not keep a collection just to make people like you happy.

Comment: @schily: "People like you" ?? What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: People that claim there are no sources for my statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about nesting a second loop within each of your directory loops to track the size of each file before it is appended to the tar file? Here's a schematic pseudo-code of what I mean:

```
max_size=$((1024*1024*1024))
total_size=0
for dir in $dirlist ; do
  for foo in $dir/*; do
    this_size="$(stat -c"%s" $foo)"
    if [ $(($total_size + $this_size)) -le $max_size ] ; then
      tar --append ... $foo
      total_size="$(($total_size + $this_size))"
    else
      # start new tar file here
      tar -c ... $foo
      total_size="$this_size"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Warning: `gtar --append` has several issues and should not not be used since it could change the archive type in the middle.

Comment: @schily Oh? What alternative do you suggest in this case?

Comment: @Chris have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, python does not understand the tar format, so you probably like to use a tar archive module that may not be 100% compatible to the tar archive standard. This is an important thing to consider, there are many half baken tar implementations that usually only support a sub-set of the official feature set.

I recommend to use the `star` option `-tsize` without bringing `star` into `multi volume` mode. This prevents `star` from splitting files in the middle, but it is unable to archive files that are greater than the specified tape size.

In case that the default shell "sh" is POSIX compliant with respect to support for "$((expr))", otherwise replace "sh -c" by "ksh -c" or similar.

...how about:

```
cd /tmp
star -C path/to/archivedir -c tsize=1G \
new-volume-script='cd /tmp;sh -c "mv vol-last.tar vol\$((\$1-1)).tar" script' \
f=vol-last.tar .
```

This keeps the created TAR archives in /tmp. You would need to manually rename vol-last.tar to the finally expected volume number. I may think of enhancing star to run the new volume script to the end of each archive, including the last one.

Comment: I've seen the star program as well and it looked tempting/good. I somehow was thinking to use out of the box tools from Debian, if they can do what I'm looking for. 

append with tar is working nicely for me so far - do you have any links to potential issues?
And the Python side is working as well with `import tarfile`

Comment: If you like to use best out of the box tools, you should switch to a OSS friendly distro and avoid Debian. If you like to get the gtar issues, have a look at their mailing list. There are frequent strange reports and the main problem is that gtar is not cleanly designed, so it does not control the various features and whether they are allowed with the current archive format.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll try it out then.